# XAML error: "The property 'VisualTree' is set more than once"

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to put two Grids in a DataTemplate.

I'm getting the following error with my code shown below.

> Error: "The property 'VisualTree' is set more than once"

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PareoItemTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="gridColorEjercicio" Height="100" Width="350" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Margin="-11,0,0,0">
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,10,15,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding letter}" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Resources/Fonts/Programa Tutorias Bold.ttf#Programa Tutorias" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding option}" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Resources/Fonts/Programa Tutorias Bold.ttf#Programa Tutorias" Width="253" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,10,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Image Source="{Binding imageURI}" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="gridPareoColorEjercicio" Height="100" Width="350" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Margin="-11,0,0,0">
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,10,15,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding letter}" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Resources/Fonts/Programa Tutorias Bold.ttf#Programa Tutorias" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding option}" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Resources/Fonts/Programa Tutorias Bold.ttf#Programa Tutorias" Width="253" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,10,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Image Source="{Binding imageURI}" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A data template can only have one visual tree but you are defining two grids. If you want the two grids to appear next to each other or one below the other, wrap them in a `StackPanel` and set the property `Orientation` accordingly.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <Grid>[...]</Grid>
      <Grid>[...]</Grid>
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I suppose what this means is: A `<DataTemplate>` can have only one immediate child element.  Is this correct?