# how to access other resources inside a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

A `DataTemplate` inside a `Resource Dictionary` needs to refer to a `Styles.xaml`, so I have the following

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WPFApp">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="resources/Styles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:MyFileInfo}">
        <Grid>
            grid stuff
        </Grid>

        <TextBlock> stuff </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>


</ResourceDictionary>
```

but there is an error at `DataTemplate` saying that `The proprety "Visual Tree" can only be set once.` What does this mean? Is it good practice to put a `DataTemplate` inside a `ResourceDictionary`? How to access other resources inside a `ResourceDictionary`?

Comment: Do you actually have `"x:Type src:MyFileInfo"` or `"{x:Type src:MyFileInfo}"`? Also refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965447/the-property-visualtree-is-set-more-than-once) question. Problem may be in _data template stuff_

Comment: oops, fixed. I think you are right; the error went away after deleting `data template stuff`...

Comment: Can you show your `DataTemplate`? Error would suggest that it contains more then one root element

Comment: @dkozl thanks, that post solved my problem. can I still delete this question? since the problem isn't really in the code

Comment: @dkozl guess not. I'll edit the error in now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DataTemplate should only have one child. Use this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:MyFileInfo}">
    <Grid>
        grid stuff
        <TextBlock> stuff </TextBlock>
    </Grid>        
</DataTemplate>
```